# What does updated means in this picture in SonarQube web UI

Tags: sonarqube

[image]
<sub>(source: [testlead.se](http://www.testlead.se/images/updated.jpg))</sub>

In SonarQube UI, when you list issues based on Severity, you will get a list of issues to drilldown. These are the coloumns in the UI.
Severity, Status, Description, Component, Assignee, Action plan and Updated.
I wonder what actually "Updated" shows?

Comment: I have now added another picture describing my question better. There are two arrows marked in the picture, what are these dates displayed? 
http://www.testlead.se/images/update2.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The "updated" column contains the date when the issue has been updated (status has changed, resolution has changed, etc...)